# Nesting and querying documents with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, document-database, odm

I have a data structure that looks more or less like this:

```
var city = {
  name: String,
  mayor: Person,
  citizens: [Person]
};
```

I think my use case is pretty good for using MongoDB, but I have a few questions. The above model has been implemented with mongoose, and I use [sub documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) to nest Persons inside City.Obviously the citizens array could get quite long, and that's why MongoDB seems like a good choice.

Is this an efficient way to structure my data? I'm wondering if Mongo will have to do some sort join each time I want to select a city, with *all* of it's citizens (or a large part of them). That would obviously defeat the purpose of using a document database.

Also, when in the mongo terminal i try something like `db.cities.find({name:'Berlin'}).mayor` I don't get any results. When I try `db.cities.find({name:'Berlin'})` it shows the city, and it also shows an object id for the mayor but not all the properties of the mayer/Person.

So how do I query *with* sub documents and is this a good way of working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend your schema as following with [`Populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). There are no `joins` in MongoDB but sometimes we still want references to documents in other collections. This is where population comes in.

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
}); 

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

var citySchema = Schema{
  name: String,
  mayor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  citizens: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
};

var City = mongoose.model('City', citySchema);
```

To query the city like `Berlin` through

```
City.find({name: 'Berlin'})
    .populate('mayor')
    .populate('citizens')
    .exec(...)
```

The `mayor` and `citizens` related document will be retrieved from DB.

If you concern there are too many `citizens` in the city to make the `city` too large with `populate` the person in the `city`, another option is

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  cityId  : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'City' }
}); 

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

var citySchema = Schema{
  name: String,
  mayor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }
};

var City = mongoose.model('City', citySchema);
```

To query the city `Berlin` with [`aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/), here are the sample codes.

```
City.find({name: 'Berlin'})
    .populate('mayor')
    .exec(function(err, city) {
       Person.aggregate([
          {$group: {cityId: city._id, citizens: {$push: '$name'}}}
          // ...
       ], function(err, result) {
          //...
});
```